# eigenvector bug?

Tags: matrix, bugs, linear-algebra

**Bug introduced in 7.0.1 or earlier and fixed in 10.0.0**

---

I have a fairly simple $3\times3$ complex matrix,
$$
M=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{7}{2}-\frac{i}{2} & -1+i & \frac{1}{2}+\frac{5 i}{2} \\
 -1+i & 5+i & -1+i \\
 \frac{1}{2}+\frac{5 i}{2} & -1+i & \frac{7}{2}-\frac{i}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Solving for the eigenvalues and eigenvectors:

```
mat = {{7/2 - I/2, -1 + I, 1/2 + 5 I/2}, {-1 + I, 
    5 + I, -1 + I}, {1/2 + 5 I/2, -1 + I, 7/2 - I/2}}; 
{vals, vecs} = Eigensystem[mat]
```

gives (Mathematica 9.0.1)

\begin{array}{ccc}
 6 & 3+3 i & 3-3 i \\
 \{1,-2,1\} & \left\{\frac{17}{13}+\frac{6 i}{13},0,1\right\} & \{-1,0,1\} \\
\end{array}

But that 2nd eigenvector is not right; it should be $(1,1,1)$.   Is there a bug, or am I being incredibly obtuse?

Comment: is this what you want:  M = {{7/2 - I/2, -1 + I, 1/2 + 5 I/2}, {-1 + I, 5 + I, -1 + I}, {1/2 + 5 I/2, -1 + I, 7/2 - I/2}}

Comment: Pretty shocking, this one. Are you going to report it to Wolfram? [http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Feedback](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Feedback)

Comment: Yup, this is clearly a bug as can be confirmed with the following: `M.Transpose[{Eigenvectors[M][[2]]}] == 
 Eigenvalues[M][[2]] Transpose[{Eigenvectors[M][[2]]}]`. Which gives `False` indicating that this is not a true eigenvalue equation. Indeed replacing this eigenvector with `{1,1,1}` satisfies the equation.

Comment: What's also troubling is that *Mathematica* get's it right sometimes. For example the matrix `{{7,0,0}, {0,1,-I}, {0,I,-1}}`.

Comment: I've pasted the matrix to WolframAlpha. It also gives the wrong answer.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. It's nice to know I'm not crazy.  I've reported it to Wolfram.

Comment: This has been fixed for a future release.

Answer (score 20):

This bug has been fixed in **V10**

```
mat = {{7/2 - I/2, -1 + I, 1/2 + 5 I/2}, {-1 + I, 
    5 + I, -1 + I}, {1/2 + 5 I/2, -1 + I, 7/2 - I/2}};

Eigensystem[mat]
```

Gives:

```
{{6, 3 + 3 I, 3 - 3 I}, {{1, -2, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}}}
```

\begin{array}{ccc}
 6 & 3+3 i & 3-3 i \\
 \{1,-2,1\} & \left\{1,1,1\right\} & \{-1,0,1\} \\
\end{array}

Answer (score 14):

This appears to be a genuine bug with exact arithmetic in `Eigensystem`. Here is a comparison to the same calculation with real numbers, for which I use the matrix `mat//N`:

```
mat = {{7/2 - I/2, -1 + I, 1/2 + 5 I/2}, {-1 + I, 
    5 + I, -1 + I}, {1/2 + 5 I/2, -1 + I, 7/2 - I/2}};

{vals, vecs} = Eigensystem[mat]

(*
==> {{6, 3 + 3 I, 
  3 - 3 I}, {{1, -2, 1}, {17/13 + (6 I)/13, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}}}
*)

{numericvals, numericvecs} = Eigensystem[mat // N] // Chop

(*
==> {{6., 3. - 3. I, 
  3. + 3. I}, {{-0.408248, 0.816497, -0.408248}, {-0.707107, 0, 
   0.707107}, {0.57735, 0.57735, 0.57735}}}
*)
```

The results are not equivalent, and I can test which of them gives correct eigenvalues as follows:

```
Table[Chop[mat.vecs[[i]] - vals[[i]] vecs[[i]]], {i, 3}]

(*
==> {{0, 0, 0}, {36/13 - (24 I)/13, -(36/13) + (24 I)/13, 0}, {0,
   0, 0}}
*)

Table[
 Chop[N[mat].numericvecs[[i]] - 
   numericvals[[i]] numericvecs[[i]]], {i, 3}]

(* ==> {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}} *)
```

Clearly, the floating-point result is correct and the exact arithmetic result (using `mat` without `N`) is incorrect.

This then also indicates how to work around this bug: use only numerical matrices with `N[...]`.

Comment: It's good to know that the numerical result is correct. I'm saved.

Comment: @xslittlegrass Sadly, the "future version" that was supposed to fix this bug hasn't materialized yet...